# Why does this forum focus on music education rather than music experience?

Tags: discussion

Most people are looking for advice on how to make pop and rock music. Sorry, but no one listens to classical or jazz. They then get distracted by eb7 to eb6(minus 5) and crap. Then they just forget about trying to actually learn real music. But then where are they supposed to go. Every forum has been taken over by the music majors and have actively shut out the musicians that know things that they don't from their work in popular music even though the musicians in popular music have spent at least as much time, if not more time, actually learning music.

Edit:

I've been asked to clarify what I mean. First of all, I don't mean that people shouldn't learn chords or key signatures. That is a given for any serious composer. The matter is just in the way they are taught. The forum is filled with questions like 'When should I use B under C, C# D and A'. That's a little exaggerated, but that's how I feel. If this is a forum meant to answer esoteric questions then fine, but you are leaving out the majority of the users out there. Stack Overflow should be inclusive and answer those questions, but I feel that the answers they give are sorely lacking. The answers delve into theory that does not apply to them which, I feel, leaves the user completely intimidated and confused, and unwilling to ask any of their more pressing questions. It is ok to at least somewhat cater to pop, rock and rap. That is what most of the people who come to this site are looking for before they get scared away.

Maybe there just aren't the right questions being asked, but I've seen this on every other forum I've looked at.

Edit:
In case someone was thinking about adding modes as the same importance as chords and key signatures I'm going to add my opinion. Modes are so easily, and so often changed and ignored that the whole concept of the is outdated and boorish.

Edit:
I can't ask Todd directly, but I just have to know. What pop/rock song actually uses that chord change?

Yet another edit:
[I'm learning to play the guitar. What chords should I learn next?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/54298/im-learning-to-play-the-guitar-what-chords-should-i-learn-next?noredirect=1#comment83086_54298)

On hold because it's opinion based. What in music is not opinion based? There are good answers, but they are all instantly discredited. There is no place for someone to actually learn music on this site.

@ general You got me there. I'm done making edits on this site.

Comment: Can you please edit your post to ask a specific question. Currently it seems to include things that are very opinion based (such as "no one listens to jazz" which is patently untrue) and almost a mild rant. Also, our focus is on practice and performance, not education. If your question is "why is our scope what it is" then the answer is that that is what the community has decided.

Comment: You edits aren't help your case. We have questions from many different backgrounds and we have answers from many different view points. If you ask you will get an answer. Also your last edit is just a rant. Modes are a very important topic, but not for the _relative_ aspect of them, but for the _parallel_ instead.

Comment: I just have to point out that this kind of "crap": "*eb7 to eb6(minus 5)*", appears in pop and rock music **all the time**, and many other genres besides. You know who is making millions of dollars with that "crap"? Just one example is Lin-Manuel Miranda, writer of *Hamilton*, who not only wrote with amazing music theory but also advanced and effective lyrical prosody. Same goes for John Mayer. Same for many more famous musicians of all genres than you might think. Just because it's not classical or jazz doesn't mean it's not it's extremely sophisticated, subtle, and the result of hard work.

Comment: This isn't a 'forum' in the normal sense, but a 'question and answer' site.  Because of this, it's important that questions are written in precise enough terms that clear answers can be given. It's true that talking about music in that way might be a bit alien to some people, but what solution are you proposing?

Comment: I'm worried about these 'changing modes'. What have I missed? Or is it just more rant...

Comment: Confirmed! Nobody listens to classical music! Only 8/10 people. http://www.classical-music.com/news/survey-shows-810-people-listen-classical-music Saying stuff like that is completely ignorant and false. The very fact that there are a lot of classical/jazz questions on this site utterly destroys that contention. (Note also, that there are plenty of questions about pop music too.) The truth is that there are a lot of people who use and benefit from this site for different reasons. We're not gonna change that because it's not "cool."

Comment: Also, SE is a tool for professionals. If you don't understand the language, then learn it and all of the sudden it will be useful to you.

Comment: This site is not a forum at all, it actively discourages 'chats'.

Answer (score 3):

Posts about performing music are just as welcome here as posts about teaching or learning.

I think a lot of questions appear to be about education because most practising musicians see what they do as an ongoing process of learning. If you have a problem with your music, it's easy to think of and describe that problem as "How do I learn to do this better?" or "What can I learn to get better at this?". There's also the fact that we're on the internet, mostly communicating by text, so answers will tend to be more theoretical: it's harder to see how you're playing to diagnose a problem, and harder to show by example, like a real teacher would.

But ultimately, the one way that Stack Exchange is like a forum site is that it's made by the visitors. If you want to see more questions about pop and rock music, ask more questions about pop and rock music. As well as improving the site yourself, you'll also be encouraging other people who are interested in pop and rock music to ask those questions, and building up that community. If you'd like to see more practically-focused answers, write more practically-focused answers.

Just don't forget that music theory is the language we use to describe musical concepts, whatever style of music we're playing. When I play in a group with a wide repertoire - hymns, showtunes, jazz, rock, folk music - the language we use to describe how to play is the same across all those styles and ages. If you hope to be able to write useful answers without naming chords or using musical terminology, you're setting yourself a difficult challenge.

Comment: I get what your saying and I appreciate your answer. Maybe my problem isn't really with stackoverflow as a whole -I know you are doing your best. But it just seems that this site has the potential to be so much better and cater to far more people. I think about my niece who is sitting down to learn the guitar and wants to write something of her own. All she knows is G and D. How can she learn that C and em are also wonderful chords. Some people don't have a teacher and will look for ways to learn how to expand themselves.

Comment: I've heard that sentiment so many times, on different sites on the network. People say "but the site could also help such-and-such people, if only we had different criteria for questions, or if we allowed more discussion, or if we allowed opinion-based questions," or some other thing. But trying to be everything to everyone is a sure way to fail. SE's rigid focus on objective questions is what sets it apart from all the forums you complain about in your question, and the founders believe that this is the best compromise between attracting good content *vs.* discouraging useless posts.

Comment: @Mardymar Even though we have some very erudite questions and answers here, we also have plenty of information about the basics. It might not always be easy to find, but it's here. And also, if you or your niece have questions that seem "basic" and you can't find answers here, ask them! I've built my rep here **much** more on the basics like how to hold a guitar, and very little on advanced concepts.

Comment: @ Everyone I understand that some people have questions about music theory and that this is the place to find good advice regarding that subset. However, I find this site inhospitable to people asking basic "what do I do next" questions. Furthermore, I find the answers to many of the questions asked to be ultimately unhelpful for a beginner in music. They just mark the answer as right, quickly forget it, then go on to things other than music.

Comment: @Mardymar I think there are examples where we get some 'what do I do next' questions that we could do better with, but there are many situations where  'what do I do next' could reasonably be almost anything, and those kind of questions don't tend to be the focus of SE sites by design.