# So we have hit 10 000 question

Tags: discussion

So I have been a little bit less active lately. I see now we have hit the 10 thousand questions mark, let us maybe take a moment to reflect on how this community has grown over the years.

I think all our users can take a moment to reflect on all our years here.

Comment: It also may be a time to reflect on why we lost certain knowledgeable and helpful contributors - Wheat in particular - and what could have been done differently to retain them and their superb answers.

Comment: @Tim Do we even know why we lost Wheat? The information in the meta seems to distill down to Matthew Read's *guess* as to why he left. Even if some people know why he left, the community as a whole doesn't really have access to that information, about Wheat or anyone else who left.

Comment: It is interesting to look how long we have out lived some predictions of doom and gloom: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/550/vote-to-close-this-forum

Comment: @Tim Looks like some people have a perception that they dislike and we aren't always (or ever?) able to shift that perception: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/why-bother-with-this-board  and https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2742/why-does-this-forum-focus-on-music-education-rather-than-music-experience

Comment: Well, I'm still here, but sometimes I wonder why. IMO sites like this "work" for the "experts" so long as information is flowing in two directions, not one. "Teaching something" (by answering questions) is fair exchange for "learning something" - but bluntly, I'm *not* learning anything much that interests me here, compared with some other SE sites, and though I have plenty of unanswered questions about music, from what I've seen here I wouldn't expect them to get worthwhile answers (except perhaps from one guy who I'm pretty sure I know IRL anyway, and who recently left...)

Comment: @alephzero - I'm ignorant when it comes to initials. IRL??

Comment: @Tim 50 bucks says it means "in real life."

Comment: In terms of stats, I do see a lot of people getting useful info but the fact we lost two very experienced individuals (one because of rudeness from a couple of others, and one because the SE framework really didn't work for him) means we have a gap in some areas we would like to encourage. It is a challenge, as @alephzero said, because if the experts get bored and leave, the site loses out. So how do we keep experts interested, aside from encouraging their teaching side?

Comment: @DrMayhem I feel like SE is a bit of a "live by the sword, die by the sword" mechanism. Meaning, the same aspects of the system that make it great in the ways it is great are also the ones that make some people hate it. Along those lines, I wonder if it's really possible to encourage certain areas of expertise in a Stack. Perhaps by well though out choices of on-topic and off-topic criteria, but that seems like the most that can be done, and that's how we have what we have today. Because MSE is created and moderated by users, it seems to have a life of its own that can't be totally controlled.